# I could not make a database table with php file

Tags: mysql

$table has been created and are ready for use! I highly suggest that you now delete **create_table.php** before you continue.";
    exit;
}
?>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean?